# Создание лифта с помощью VUEjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
<template>
<div>
  <table width="20%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="63">
   <tr id="5"> 
    <td width="200" valign="top"></td>
    <td id="fith_floor" valign="top"><button id="fith_floor" inner-height="70"></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="4">
    <td width="200" valign="top"></td>
    <td id="fourth_floor" valign="top"><button id="fourth_floor" inner-height="70"></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="3">
    <td width="200" valign="top"></td>
    <td id="third_floor" valign="top"><button id="third_floor" inner-height="70"></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="2">
    <td width="200" valign="top"></td>
    <td id="second_floor" valign="top"><button id="second_floor" inner-height="70"></button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="1">
    <td class="lift" width="5"  valign="top"></td>
    <td id="first_floor" valign="top"><button id="first_floor" inner-height="70"></button></td>
   </tr>

  </table>

</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    
  }
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .first_floor{
    font-size: 10;
  }
  .lift{
    background: blue;
  }

</style>
```

Хочу создать лифт, который передвигается к нажатой кнопке, а если нажато несколько кнопок, то появляется очередь из этажей, к которым лифт будет подниматься. Мой вариант - это менять строку в таблице с (пустой) строкой, где нажата кнопка, но я не знаю как это сделать (и можно ли это сделать)

Comment: Также есть вариант с удалением одного столбца и просто менять класс лифта